# Unable to access properties of a class using .(dot) operator inside ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Event Though it's printing the Instance of 'Event' I'm unable to access its properties.**

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          print(events[index]);
    }
```

**Event Class**

```
class Event {
  String Date;
  String FullDate;
  String BookinkStatus;
  String BookinkStatusId;
  String BookingColorHEX;
  String BookingText;
  String SecondText;
  String OnlyDate;
  bool IsFee;
}
```

**console output**

```
Instance of 'Event'
Instance of 'Event'
Instance of 'Event'
```

**If I use the dot operator then it's throwing error.**
***The getter 'Date' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.***

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          print(events[index].Date);
    }
```

**Full Code**

```
calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
                  markerBuilder: (BuildContext context, date, events) {
                    if (events.isEmpty) return SizedBox();
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: events.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          print(events[index]!.Date);
                          return Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                            child: Container(
                                // height: 7,
                                width: 5,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Colors.black54)),
                          );
                        });
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: `calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders<Event>(`

Comment: thanks begginer mistakes

Answer (score -1):

For using .dot operator you need to use Constructor

```dart
class Event {
  String Date;
  String FullDate;
  String BookinkStatus;
  String BookinkStatusId;
  String BookingColorHEX;
  String BookingText;
  String SecondText;
  String OnlyDate;
  bool IsFee;
}

Event({
this.Date,
this.FullDate,
this.BookinkStatus,
this.BookinkStatusId,
this.BookingColorHEX,
this.BookingText,
this.SecondText,
this.OnlyDate,
this.IsFee,
});
```

Comment: i've remove because of code limit, i had it in my code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a customized "class Event" in List and ListTile.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp(
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Login MoneyFlutter'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _counter = 0;
  late final List<Event> items = [];
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var num = 5;
    for( var i = 0 ; i <= 10; i++ ) {
      Event testEvent = Event(
      ) ;
      testEvent.Date= '2022-01-02';
      testEvent.index= i;
      items.add(testEvent);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Date: ${items[index].Date}'),
            subtitle: Text('Index: ${items[index].index} '),
          );
        },
      ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class Event {
  late String Date;
  late int index;
  // late String BookinkStatus;
  // late String BookinkStatusId;
  // late String BookingColorHEX;
  // late String BookingText;
  // late String SecondText;
  // late String OnlyDate;
  // late bool IsFee;
}
```

[image]